# Template pattern for strings in Scala to produce new objects

Tags: ruby, scala, design-patterns

Is it possible in Scala to create a string, which gets code of a class or method declaration which will be then executed and after that new objects will be created?

Here is an example in ruby code:

```
"class #{name}; def #{method_name}; \"#{block.call}\"; end; end"
```

Do you know any examples or links for my approach?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: While possible, this inherently throws away the possibility of static typechecking (between the newly-created and existing code).  Thus, the first instinct should probably be "don't do that".  If it really is necessary, then it's possible to invoke the compiler.

Comment: You probably can solve the underlying problem by abstracting over it.

Comment: @pedrofurla, that comment could probably be added to every question on SO :)

Comment: @Paul, that's probably true. But this case seems to be a crude lack of abstraction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you can get this somehow working by calling the compiler with a given String, and then you probably need a custom classloader. However Scala is a static language, so it will never be as convenient and elegant as in Ruby or other dynamic languages.

[Edit]

I never tried it, but I found this link: http://scala-programming-language.1934581.n4.nabble.com/Compiling-a-Scala-Snippet-at-run-time-td2000704.html

Comment: Hi Landei, thanks for the fast response. Can you give me a small code example, how I can use it?

Comment: I defy you to supply an example in Ruby where Scala can't be just as elegant. Not simply duplicating a particular language feature, but something in the order of an entire user story.

Comment: Of course you are right that the overall elegance of both languages is about at the same level. I implied "... for that kind of type hackery", I was just to polite to write that :-)

Answer (score 1):

Design patterns are made to circumvent common problem with a common solution. Here you are trying to use a foreign design pattern and try to translate it word by word. Be careful, particularly with dynamic language patterns.

Specifically for your question, the template pattern in Java is commonly a language construct named `abstract class`es. In Scala you can also make `abstract class`es and `trait`s.

Another trap, the singleton design pattern is a language construct in Scala.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what higher-level problem you are trying to solve, but I imagine the Scala REPL must do this all the time when you enter lines of code interactively. I seem to recall developers have successfully integrated this with applications that need to generate code dynamically.

However, as Rex points out, there are probably better solutions to your underlying problem than resorting to sloppy, unsafe mechanisms such as this.